# The sum of the angle between two vectors and their intermediate vector is greater than the total angle

Tags: vectors

I have two vectors $\vec{A}(2.735, -4.737)$ and $\vec{B}(2.735, 4.737)$, and a vector $\vec{P}(1.380, -0.796)$ in between these two vectors. When I calculate the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ it is $120$ degrees. However, the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec P$ is $ 60$ degrees and that of $\vec P$ and $\vec B$ is $90$ degrees. So the sum of individual angles $(150)$ is greater than the total angle.  Why is this anomaly?  [Here is a plot of the three vectors $\vec A,\vec B$ and $\vec P$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDzzh.png)

Comment: Please include more information about your problem, i.e. how got these values.

Comment: The angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{P}$ is (approximately) $30°.$

Comment: This could happen in 3D; it's the triangle inequality in spherical geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{P}$ is
$$\begin{align}\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{A}\cdot\vec{P}}{\left\|\vec{A}\right\|\left\|\vec{P}\right\|}\right)&=\arccos\left(\frac{2.735\cdot1.38+(-4.737)(-0.796)}{\sqrt{2.735^2+(-4.737)^2}\sqrt{1.38^2+(-0.796)^2}}\right)\\
&=\arccos(0.86583\ldots)\\
&=30^\circ\end{align}$$
so you just made a calculation error.